# In Java how to extract string from the phrase with split() function

Tags: java, split

Can I extract string from the phrase using split() function with subphrases as delimeters? For example I have a phrase "Mandatory string - Any string1 - Any string2". How can I extract "Any string1" with delimiters as "Mandatory string" and "[a-zA-Z]"

This is how I'm trying to extract:

```
String str="Mandatory string - Any string1 - Any string2";
String[] result= str.split("Mandatory\\string\\s-\\s|\\s-\\s[a-zA-Z]+");
```

Result of this code is

```
result = ["Mandatory string","ny string1","ny string2"]
```

But desired is:

```
result = ["Any string1"]
```

Could appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String[] result= str.split("Mandatory\\s(1)string\\s-\\s|\\s-\\s[a-zA-Z\\s(2)]+");`

You just forgot an "s" in position(1)
and there should be a "\\s" in position(2)

try this line:
`String[] result= str.split("Mandatory\\sstring\\s-\\s|\\s-\\s[a-zA-Z\\s]+");`

Comment: It's looks like working, but there are still some bug. The result is: result=[" ","Any string1"]

Comment: Yes, if the rex matches the first part of a String, the first element in the result array will be a "", just use the result[1] as the result you want.

Comment: The result of `" -".split(" ");` will be ["","-"] all the time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's a typo right here:

```
Mandatory\\string
```

This should probably read

```
Mandatory\\sstring
```

Anyway, I would either use " - " as the delimiter and get the second token:

```
str.split(" - ")[1] // TODO: prod version should do bounds checking etc
```

or use a different tool entirely, probably a regex match with the following regular expression:

```
"Mandatory string - (.*) - .*"
```

The parenthesised capture group will give you the string you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a definite format to your input string, just split it and then use the parts that are needed:

```
String[] resultArray = str.split(" - ");
String whatYouWant = resultArray[1];
```

Comment: Ok,I got this. But if I don't know array index?

Comment: @Andriy Well you want the first string - that's going to be index 1 (assuming it exists. You may need to check to verify it does exist before using it to avoid an exception.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
String[] result = str.split(" - ");
return result.length < 2 ? "" : result[1];
```